# Highlight changes in a table (ASP/MVC5)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm developing a Web small application designed to display stock quotes.

To do so I have created a controller (TradingController) designed to retrieve all the quotes from my service layer.

```
public class TradingController : Controller
{
    private readonly IQuoteService _service;
    private readonly IQuoteMapper _mapper;

    // GET: TradingPlace
    public TradingController(IQuoteService service, IQuoteMapper mapper)
    {
        _service = service;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_mapper.MapToViewModel(_service.GetRealtimeQuotes()));
    }

    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult AutoRefresh()
    {
        return PartialView("_Quotes", _mapper.MapToViewModel(_service.GetRealtimeQuotes()));
    }
}
```

The last method (AutoRefresh) is called directly from the view to automatically refresh the table with "real-time" information.

```
<div id="quotes">
    @Html.Partial("_Quotes", Model)
</div>

<script>
    function Refresh() { $('#quotes').load('@Url.Action("AutoRefresh",   "Trading")'); }
    setInterval(Refresh, 2500);
</script>
```

> I trying to find a way to highlight values that change. My ultimate goal would be to display a trend (the value is increasing/decreasing...).

Is there a simple way to achieve that?

Thank you,

Seb.

Comment: Rather than returning a partial view, you could return json data to update the DOM, and compare the new values with the previous json data (i.e. cached on the client)

Comment: That's a very good one thank you. Is there an API to help me compare and then generate the table?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but would be easy to implement. If your always returning the same stock codes i the same order, it would only be a couple of lines of jquery code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to highlight changes, at the very least you'd need to be able to identify a "change".  Which will involve having a copy of the previous data, a copy of the new data, and a way to examine them.

Can this be done server-side?

That is, can the implementation within `_service.GetRealtimeQuotes()` "know" when something is a "change"?  Maybe by a "last updated" timestamp on that record, or by some other means?  If so then that can be included in the model and the view can simply respond to that property.  So the model might have something like this:

```
public bool Changed
{
    get
    {
        // return true of some timestamp is less than a minute old?
        // or less than 30 seconds old?
        // or by some other comparison logic?
    }
}
```

Then the view which displays these items can bind to that.  Assuming there's a list of these objects being iterated over in the view, it might look something like this:

```
<span class="@(item.Changed ? "changed" : "normal")">@item.CurrentValue</span>
```

This would modify the CSS class for "changed" elements.

If this *can't* be done server-side, then it would likely take a bit more work client-side.  It's a bit bigger for a free-hand proof of concept here, but the basic idea would be:

- Change the AJAX to return data instead of a view, and re-populate the DOM from that data in client-side code.
- Store the array of data in client-side code.
- When you fetch a new array of data from AJAX, loop through it and compare the records to the current data.
- For each "changed" record, flag it as such in the data object.
- Re-populate the DOM from the data, similarly modifying CSS classes based on the flag.

Comment: In fact, I forgot to mention that within a quote some properties may may change, some other may not. For instance, the volume always increase but the price may fluctuate depending on the market. To do perform the comparison on the server side i would need to maintain a boolean for every properties which doesn't seem to be the best approach. I like your second option. I will try to implement it.. Thank you